# How to bake or compute my script data before play

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I am working on a unity project that involves a lot of math. It takes about 1-2 seconds for the math to finish on start.

Is there any way to "bake" or "compute" this data before the game starts. I saw something similar done in [this script](https://github.com/ecidevilin/UnityMeshSimplify/blob/master/Assets/MeshSimplify/Scripts/MeshSimplify/MeshSimplify.cs) from [this project](https://github.com/ecidevilin/UnityMeshSimplify?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=95D3CC455D674CE48F7AE9E2DDB9132E). My project has nothing to do with this script, it is just an example.

I would prefer not to share my code. I need to compute the variables from a method called `Initialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I fixed this by using `[SerializeField, HideInInspector]` before the variables I wanted to bake.
2. Then I would create a new class (can be in the same script). You have to `using UnityEditor` then your class should be something like

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(classToBake))]
public class BakeGUI : Editor
{

}
```

3. Call function `override public void OnInspectorGUI()` then call functions of the type `EditorGUILayout` Then you have to create a variable of the type of script.

```
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(classToBake))]
public class BakeGUI: Editor
{
    override public void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        classToBake bake = (classToBake)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Compile Data"))
        {
            bake.Compile();
        }
        if (GUILayout.Button("Delete Data"))
        {
            bake.ResetData();
        }
        DrawDefaultInspector();
    }
}
```

### Finally, how to use this.

- change `classtoBake` to the script with the data you want to bake
- In the if statements, you can run methods when they click the buttons.

## The most important thing

After you have this working, to save your data, **YOU MUST** have the variables you are going to change have the attributes `[SerializeField, HideInInspector]`